# Using the gcloud CLI tool, and given the id of the instance, how do you get the project?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, gcloud

I am working on automating the collection of "evidence" for an audit. The Auditors have given me a list of GCP instances to collect data on. Some of this involves getting the firewall data, for which I need the project.

We have over 300 projects in GCP. The auditors gave me a the instance ID, and a FQDN that we create and put in our DNS.

SO what I'm looking for is some sort of incantation like `gcloud projects list --id=8675309`, but Google (the search engine, not the cloud provider) doesn't want me to find it today.

Rephrasing to simplify the question:

I am given a list of GCP instances by auditors. Meaning that I have no control over what information they give me. I can extract the instance ID of a VM from that list. E.G.:

```
top-1404255003473941074.client1.example.com  -> 1404255003473941074
bot-4104033772852034975.client2.example.com  -> 4104033772852034975
inf-2193649402447445175.example.com          -> 2193649402447445175
```

And I would greatly like to so something like:

```
for instance_line in $(sort -n -k4 -t',' $instance_list)
do
    instance_id=$(some awk stuff, some sed stuff) 
    project=$(gcloud please give me the project that $instance_id belongs to.) 
    ...
done
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking for.  Please include the Google Cloud Platform resources (such as GCP Cloud DNS) involved, some Cloud SDK (`gcloud`) commands you have already tried and the expected & actual output of those commands.  I can see that you've already included a sample `gcloud` command, but `--id` isn't a valid flag for the `list` command.

Answer (score 1):

There's a (new) service provided by Google that inventories `Organization`'al resources. This may be a better choice: [Cloud Asset Inventory](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory)

I think you'll have to invert the problem because (!?) instances are 'owned' by projects (not the other way around).

- So you would have to enumerate all your projects
- Enumerate the instances within the project
- Determine the public IPs of these instances
- Map the FQDN Cloud DNS A records to the list of public IPs

You will have difficulties correlating firewall rules to instances unless the firewall rule explicitly maps to instances e.g. by labels. Even then, the Compute Engine metadata doesn't describe ports that the instance's services may use.

pseudo-`gcloud`:

```sh
# Assume that the auth'd  account can access all the Org's projects
# Otherwise you'll want to replace the command with a list
PROJECTS=$(gcloud projects list --format="value(projectId)"

for PROJECT in ${PROJECTS}
do
  # From docs as I don't have any instances running
  # Returns a CSV to facilitate parsing
  # Potentially pull networkInterfaces too for public IPs
  # https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/list
  INSTANCES=$(gcloud compute instances list \
  --project=${PROJECT} \
  --format="csv[no-heading](id,name)")
  for INSTANCE in ${INSTANCES}
  do
    IFS=, read ID NAME <<< ${INSTANCE}
    printf "Instance %s (%s)\n" ${ID} ${NAME}
    ...
  done
done
```